# How "call" helper(effect) function in redux-saga return the resolved value instead a promise?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-saga

I do not understand what the mechanism of the call method is and that it should naturally yield a promise, but instead return the resolved value of that promise.

line 14:

```
import { put, call, takeLatest } from "redux-saga/effects";
import * as api from "./api";
//generate watchers
function* rootSaga() {
  //define watcher
  yield takeLatest("FETCH_TASKS_STARTED", fetchTasks);
}
//watcher is subProgram.They are executed when an particular action of the dispatched
function* fetchTasks() {
  try {
    yield put({
      type: "REQUEST_STARTED",
    });
    const { data } = yield call(api.fetchTasks);
    yield put({
      type: "FETCH_TASKS_SUCCEED",
      payLoad: { tasks: data },
    });
  } catch (e) {
    yield put({
      type: "REQUEST_FAILED",
      payLoad: { error: e.message },
    });
  }
}
export default rootSaga;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The source code for the call effect [can be found here](https://github.com/redux-saga/redux-saga/blob/master/packages/core/src/internal/effectRunnerMap.js#L107)

The call effect starts by calling whatever you asked it to call, then it checks what was returned. If you [return a promise](https://github.com/redux-saga/redux-saga/blob/master/packages/core/src/internal/effectRunnerMap.js#L113) (eg, if you use `call` with an async function), it waits for that promise to resolve, via a helper function called `resolvePromise`. resolvePromise basically just calls `.then` on the promise, passing in a callback. The callback is the function that knows how to resume the saga, which it will do by calling `.next()`.

If you [return an iterator](https://github.com/redux-saga/redux-saga/blob/master/packages/core/src/internal/effectRunnerMap.js#L117) (eg, if you use `call` with a saga), it hands control over to the `proc` function, which is the function responsible for running sagas. That code also checks for promises and waits for them to resolve, on [this line](https://github.com/redux-saga/redux-saga/blob/master/packages/core/src/internal/proc.js#L142)

Comment: So how does it wait? Eventually the execution becomes asynchronous and the CALL function does not return anything !!!!

Comment: @miladshiriyan It doesn't "wait" synchronously. The `yield` stops the saga, and its execution is only resumed once the promise is fulfilled.

Comment: Please see line 14
When the call is called, it actually solves a promise, but not synchronously. This means that in the .next call on generator, because the fetchTask function itself is executed simultaneously, it goes to the next yiled without waiting and does not wait. So the question is how the function on line 14 stops to solve the promise

Comment: @Bergi Ah ... so the callback function actually call .next  after resolve the promise

Comment: Since you used the `yield` keyword, your generator function stops running. Execution makes its way to `runCallEffect` (the first link in my post). `runCallEffect` calls `api.fetchTasks`, which returns a promise. Since a promise was returned, `runCallEffect` calls `.then` on the promise, passing in `cb` as the callback of the promise. The effect is now done running, and the entire execution stack unwinds. Some time later, the promise resolves, and `cb` is called. `cb` is the function for resuming the saga, so `cb` calls `.next()` on the saga's iterator, passing in the promise's result

Comment: suppose we passed an async function like with an API call to call, how do we get the response of that call into the saga? can anyone help me?